# field value being truncated in javascript remoting response

Tags: javascript-remoting

I've tested the following scenario after tracking down a bug. Can anyone else confirm this is an issue with Salesforce or am I missing something?

Replication steps:

1. create a 14-4 percent field on Contact
2. populate the field on a new Contact 'frank smith' with '12345678901234.1234'
3. setup a javascript remoting call to get 'frank smith' and the new percent field
4. inspect the result from the javascript remoting call and observe the result is '12345678901234.123'

Sample VF page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="Ctl_TestPercent">
<head>
<script>
var findCon = '{!$RemoteAction.Ctl_TestPercent.findCon}';

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(  
findCon,
function(result, event) {
    // if there was an error
    if (event.type=='exception') {              
        alert(result);
        console.log('error result:' + result);
    }
    // if there was no error continue
    else {
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById('jsresult').innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
    }
}
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--  standard result -->
{!con.percent_14_4__c}
<!-- remoting result -->
<div id="jsresult"></div>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

controller **(insert the new contact's ID in the two queries)** :

```
public with sharing class Ctl_TestPercent {
    public Contact con {get;set;}

    public Ctl_TestPercent() {
        con = [SELECT Id,Percent_14_4__c FROM Contact WHERE Id='INSERT ID'];
    }

     @remoteAction
    public static Contact findCon() {
        Contact thisCon = [SELECT Id,Percent_14_4__c FROM Contact WHERE Id='INSERT ID'];
        return thisCon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try serializing/parsing a JSON string to get around the limitation that @Ashwani mentioned.

Comment: @MosheKarmel thats a good idea, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a limitation or bug in Salesforce.

It is the limitation of Javascript memory allocation of a number with decimals. You can not go beyond 17 digits and 64 bit (approx.) number which has decimal in it.

> In javascript, the maximum number of decimals is 17, 
>   technically Sign 1 bit (63) bit

See following examples:

```
var n = 12345678901234.1234;
console.log(n+'  '+((n+'').length));
12345678901234.123  18

var n = 92345678901234.1234;
console.log(n+'  '+((n+'').length));
92345678901234.12  17
```

Even many other languages and database column types have such limitation including Salesforce.